# BOOST program_options: parsing multiple argument list

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I would like to pass the multiple arguments with positive or negative values.
Is it possible to parse it?

Currently I have a following initialization:

```
vector<int> IDlist;
namespace po = boost::program_options;     
po::options_description commands("Allowed options");
            commands.add_options()              
                ("IDlist",po::value< vector<int> >(&IDlist)->multitoken(), "Which IDs to trace: ex. --IDlist=0 1 200 -2")
                ("help","print help")
                ;
```

and I would like to call:

```
./test_ids.x --IDlist=0 1 200 -2
unknown option -2
```

So,the program_options assumes that I am passing **-2** as an another option.

Can I configure the program_options in such a way that it can accept the negative integer values?

Thanks 
Arman.

**EDIT:**
BTW I was parsing it by the simple parser

```
store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(commands).run(), vm);
```

, but [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539077/boost-program-options-parsing-multiple-argument-list/2539181#2539181) was to use the extended one:

```
parse_command_line
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>Have you tried "-2"?</strike>

*Edit:* Quoting doesn't seem to do the trick, however, changing the command line style works:

```
char* v[] = {"name","--IDlist=0","1","200","-2"};
int c = 5;

std::vector<int> IDlist;

namespace po = boost::program_options;     
po::options_description commands("Allowed options");
commands.add_options()              
    ("IDlist",po::value< std::vector<int> >(&IDlist)->multitoken(), "Which IDs to trace: ex. --IDlist=0 1 200 -2")
    ("help","print help")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(parse_command_line(c, v, commands, po::command_line_style::unix_style ^ po::command_line_style::allow_short), vm);
po::notify(vm);

BOOST_FOREACH(int id, IDlist)
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
```

Comment: program_options are stripping "" , so "-2" became -2, also the \-2 takes as \-2 option, the single quotes '-2' stays as it is.

Comment: So the quotes are stripped and it is interpreted as another option? That is odd, from the documentation[1] it seemed like it would be the way to go.

  [1]http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#id1419101

Comment: I suppose quoting the entire list doesn't work either? (--IDlist="0 1 200 -2")

Comment: yes, if I pass 
--IDlist="-0  100" the output is: 
in option 'IDlist': invalid option value '-0  100'

Seems to me I should take IDlist as a vector of strings, then convert them to integers.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable way to go about it. Not very satisfying though, you'd expect program_options to be able to handle that situation...

Comment: It is the shell that is stripping the quotes.

Comment: @Vladimir: good to know, actually I was testing it on WinXP, is it same on linux shells?

Comment: Arman -- I actually meant the Linux shell -- which creates an array of arguments and when doing so, processes quotes. On Windows, the command line is passed to the CreateProcess call, and then, I believe, stripping of quotes happens somewhere in runtime.

Answer (score 9):

**NOTE:** this is a remark to the accepted solution.

Disabling short options is the key. The solution above proposed by *kloffy* works great, but if you happen to use `positional_option_description` (e.g. to parse parameters without using an option like `ls file.txt instead of ls --file=file.txt`) you might have a hard time converting your code to do that using `parse_command_line`.

However you can also disable short options and keep using the `basic_command_line_parser` like this:

Replace

```
store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(commands).run(), vm);
```

with

```
store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(commands).style(
po::command_line_style::unix_style ^ po::command_line_style::allow_short
).run(), vm);
```

Comment: Good point. Facing the same problem, I ended up reading the numbers as strings and asing the user to use quotes for negative numbers, to avoid disabling short options.

Answer (score -1):

maybe try --IDlist "0, 1, 200, -2" or --IDlist="0, 1, 200, -2"